# Cannot connect to SQL Server database from VS2019 on my ASP.Net project

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have been trying to open my SQL Server database in Server Explorer, and I'm always getting the following error

> Connection Timeout Expired. The timeout period elapsed while attempting to consume the pre-login handshake acknowledgement. This could be because the pre-login handshake failed or the server was unable to respond back in time. The duration spent while attempting to connect to this server was -[Pre-Login] initialization=18214; handshake=118555;

I've tried to fix the issue by repairing the VS2019, and that didn't work.

**Edit:** The database is running locally from my PC.
And this is the connection string from Web.config file:

```
<add name="UserEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.UsersModel.csdl|res://*/Models.UsersModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.UsersModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=Mizile;initial catalog=Login;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Comment: [Why should I "tag my RDBMS"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) - please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: Also let us know if the DB is local or on the web, if you can provide the connection string it can help, (replace your personal informations by ***).

Comment: @B.S. I just added them.

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15488922/connection-to-sql-server-works-sometimes

Answer (score 0):

You're connection string is incorrect. If SQL Server is on your machine locally, or on your network then it CAN look something like this,

```
<add name="UserEntities" connectionString="Data Source=YourSqlInstanceName;Initial Catalog=YourDatabaseName;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

You can of course read MS docs about different types too.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/creating-a-connection-string

Answer (score 0):

I have an answer that I posted previously here:

[Connection string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65446465/14718192)

Please follow the steps to get your connection string, if successful share your experience and mark as answered else let us know where you are stuck that I will edit with more help.